How to politely point out I need a written agreement for paid work?
I recently connected with someone who owns a small business. He wants to hire me part time as a contractor. We verbally agreed on a pay rate and I signed an NDA. I don't like wordy legal documents. But I think it would be good to have a few more details in writing. For example the pay rate, pay schedule and expected work hours.
How should I bring this up?
We were scheduled for a call today, which I thought would be more to hash out these details. Instead he wanted to onboard me into the system and show me how to connect etc. He did say I would be paid for this time. In general I trust this person, but we haven't really sorted out the details of the work arrangement.
Secondary questions: Do contractors normally get paid for time taken to onboard? How about for travel time to clients' sites?

Contractors can virtually be payed for anything that is agreed upon. However, I personally wouldn’t pay to negotiate a contract with a contractor, which is essentially your question about onboarding. While you having to travel to the work site would be something I assume was part of your already agreed upon rate.

Please add a jurisdiction, this not only impacts what is usually done for cases like yours but also what is actually legal.

"In general I trust this person but we haven't really sorted out the details of the work arrangement." Well obviously, that person doesn't trust because they made you sign an NDA. You're getting scammed right now. But we can't really help you, you haven't said which jurisdiction you're in, or for how long the contract is supposed to be.

You are as valuable as enforce your clients to respect your time. Without a contract there is no reason for you to be shown how to connect, etc. You charge for your time, experience, and skillset. The scope of work and agreed price should be in a contract or SOW. They don't have to be complex. If in the future you want to comp something, that is up to you, it is a horrible way to start a business relationship. You wouldn't walk into a business and just take something without the expectation of paying? (I hope) Neither should your client treat you that way.

Thanks for all the great feedback! I sort of meant how do I actually have this conversation? For example should I email him "When is a good time to have a phone call to discuss the specifics of the work arrangement such as work hours?" How do I bring these things up? I had thought are scheduled call was to go over these details. Not paid on boarding tasks.

@PoliteShark, "When is a good time to have a phone call to discuss the specifics of the work arrangement such as work hours?" I'm sorry, but you're far too timid. And again, you haven't said which jurisdiction you're in, or for how long the contract is supposed to be. Also, tell us what kind of deliverables are they expecting, because that's potentially some leverage you could use. But if you can't give us those details, we can't really help you.


How should I bring this up?

Draw up a contract detailing these items. Both parties should agree to, and sign the contract. You may want to enlist the assistance of an attorney for this. I don't do anything for, or with, a client until I have a signed contract in place.

Do contractors normally get paid for time taken to onboard?

Yes. As a self employed contractor I make sure I bill for all of the time that I'm engaged with a client. You wouldn't be doing these things otherwise. Any time you spend engaged with this client is time you can't be engaged with, and earning money from, other clients.

How about for travel time to client sites?

Yes. You wouldn't be travelling to the client sites except on behalf of your client. Any time you spend travelling on behalf of your client is time you can't be engaged with, and earning money from, other clients.
Additionally, look into what the appropriate type of business insurance you need is. I personally carry PLI and GLI insurance to protect me, and my clients.

Will you please explain PLI and GLI? Even if they are not critical for the answer, I am curious. LI might be "Limited Insurance", P might be "Personal", but "G"?

Personal Liability Insurance and General Liability Insurance. If you're an independent contractor in the USA you need/should have both. I'll tell you that I use Hiscox Insurance for this. - https://www.hiscox.com/

Do contractors normally charge a bit more for travel time to cover the cost of gas?

I don't know about other contractors, but I charge my full hourly rate for travel. If I incur any client related expenses I submit those as expenses. I submit my mileage with my yearly federal tax filing as an IRS tax deduction. Do I charge the client for fuel, vehicle maintenance, etc.? No, that's what the federal tax mileage deduction is for.

My standard procedure:

I write up a Statement of Work (SOW), that scopes the work, the deliverables, timing, etc. Ideally the client should do this, but most of them can't, so I just do it myself.
Review the SOW and adjust as needed. This can be quite helpful to sort any miscommunications up front.
I attach the quote to the SOW either as a single number or an hourly rate plus expenses. I rather have the sticker shock now than later.
Have the client accept the quote in writing and (if they are big enough) issue a Purchase Order against you can invoice.

Of course, changes do happen, but you just follow the same process, update the SOW, quote, accept, update PO, and life goes on.
The beauty of this process is that most things that can go sideways are tackled up front before the work actually starts and you know exactly what to work on. It is more work up front but in in my experience it makes for mostly smooth sailing during the project itself. You may occasionally lose a client over it but that's ok by me: the best way to avoid the project/client from hell is not to start in the first place.

+1, it's not his job to write up a contract for an independent contractor, it's your job to come in with one.

You do not need a written agreement, you need a contract for work. And in that contract you specify the claims for salary, benefits, obligations, traveling costs, busuness trip costs, special payments, overtime salary rates... And you negotiate those terms until an agreement is reached... hopefully.
Please note that an NDA is not an employment contract. It is just a strong promise that you will not share with others whatever information is protected by that NDA.
So... until you have a proper contract, registered to the right authorities etc. ... you are just a dude (or dudette) working on the black market.

Questions like these are best answered on the Freelancing Stack Exchange.  You'll find much more depth there.  Workplace is more employment-focused than contracting, and many of the answers will come from an IT focus from the horde of nerds like me (smile) who are here.
This might be a fitting place to start, but keep digging.  It will give you justifications as to WHY a contract is important.  If you bring this up with your acquaintance and there's a reluctance to put things in writing, DO NOT TAKE THE JOB.
Beside what you learn on Freelancing Stack Exchange, please research "payment terms" as relates to accounting.  Your contract must state payment terms, or you can end up in a world of misery trying to get yourself paid.
Best of luck.

Contractors get paid for what they ask for.  If you don't ask for it, you don't get paid.
As an example, I recently accepted a project.  We were emailing, and I was happy to spend time discussing things.  I was noting down the hours spent and was intending to put that in the quote.
Then they requested me to come over for a visit.  I was upfront and said I would expect to be paid for travel, accommodation and time spent on site.  They agreed.  And paid up when invoiced.
When I gave them a quote, I requested a deposit. As far as I know, this is not common for software contractors.  The reason -  I trusted the person I was dealing with, but it is not his company.  His boss could override him  and even cancel the project once I had started.  They wanted my services, so they paid up.
The project is long, so I also wanted progress payments.  To make it easier, I broke the job into five stages and costed them.  I made it clear that the first stage was a fixed price, the other stages were estimates.  This is because, things will change as we go along.
